# Xamarin IOS Build error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated

Tags: xamarin.ios, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

Trying to build an IPA for Xamarin iOS and I'm getting the following error.

```
error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.
```

When I double click on the error, it opens Mobile.BuildTools.targets and shows the error happening on this line.

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <__Generated_dSYM Include="$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('$(IpaPackagePath)'))\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

So the problem must be that the variable "IpaPackagePath" is empty but how do I resolve it?

Comment: You can try to check Build IPA for all your build configs (DEBUG, RELEASE) and then build again. The option is in iOS.project properties-> iOS IPA Options Tab.

Comment: 3 years later and now using Visual Studio 2022 and I'm back to getting this error.  Ugh.  Nothing in any of my build configs under iOS IPA options has a path in it that should be causing this error.

Comment: My "fix" for this is the same fix for numerous weird Xamarin related bugs.  Close VS, delete all bin and obj folders, open VS, clean and rebuild.

Comment: " Close VS, delete all bin and obj folders, open VS, clean and rebuild" didn't work for me